# Maximum value of 8051 mode 0 timers (13 bit timer)

Tags: 8051

In the mode 0 timer (13 bit) of 8051, the entire 8 bits of TH and the lower 5 bits if TL are used. Then the highest value possible for the timer should be 0FF1F H but in many sources, it is given as 1FFF H. Why?

Answer (score 1):

1FFF H suggests the maximum value till timer in 13 bit mode can go. In 13 bit mode, significant 13 bits of the counter are : TH[7:0]-TL[7:3].

Hope it helps.